# A series involving binomial coefficient

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, limits, binomial-coefficients

My main question is how to evaluate (we can simplify it a little, but it doesn't seem to help):
$$1-\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{t=0}^{x-1}\left(\binom{6x}{t}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{t}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{6 x-t}\right)$$

The problem I came across was (in this [article](https://www.madandmoonly.com/doctormatt/mathematics/dice1.pdf), p. $23$):

> What is the most probable: rolling at least one six with six dice, at
> least two sixes with twelve dice, or at least three sixes with
> eighteen dice?

This is a standard binomial probability problem, but I'm interested in the limiting case; suppose we are trying to find the probability of rolling at least 1000000000 six's with 6000000000 dice. Experimentally, the probability seems very close to $0.5$, but how do I justify this?

Comment: By the central limit theorem, the distribution approaches the associated normal, which is, of course, symmetric about the mean.

Comment: +1 for a good question which motivates using the central limit theorem (i.e that it isn't some contrived exercise from your textbook).

Comment: Unrelated: You were using `\array` to typeset the binomial coefficient, I have now changed it to `\binom`.

Comment: Thank you for helping out, I have now fully understood the simple explanation.